# ¿Cómo evitar insertar comillas simples en base de datos si es valor nulo?

Tags: php, html5, postgresql, php5

Tengo un problema con las validaciones de campos que no pueden pasar vacíos desde un formulario. Desde la base de datos, los campos obligatorios están como `NOT NULL`, **pero cuando el usuario deja vacío un campo obligatorio en el formulario, éste igual pasa el registro, porque en la base de datos, se registran las comillas simples ''** en vez de validar que no puede proceder el registro porque no deberían ser nulos, y si quito las comillas simples en la consulta para hacer la inserción, me da errores, pues para registrar strings necesita las comillas simples.

Aquí mi consulta de inserción:

`$insert_value = "INSERT INTO equipos (id_secuencia, modelo, marca, tecnologia, sin_ivaa, con_ivaa, android, windows, bada, symbian, fecha_marcaje, detalle_hablador, tactil, tda, camara_foto, camara_video,mp3, mp4, internet, wifi, gps, bluetooth, social, microsd, pc, sms, mms, email, calculadora, alarma, vibracion, altavoz, directorio, tv, radio, usb, qwerty, editor, juegos, neo) VALUES (1,'$modelo','$marca','$tecnologia',$precioSinIva,$precioConIva,'$android','$Bada','$Symbian','$Windows_Mobile','$FechaMarcaje','$DetalleHablador','$PantallaTactil','$TvDigital','$CamaraFotografica','$CamaraVideo','$mp3','$mp4','$internet','$wifi','$gps','$bluetooth','$accesoRedesSociales','$RanuraMicroSd','$sincronizacionPC','$MensajeTexto','$MensajeMultimedia','$CorreoElectronico','$Calculadora','$Despertador','$Vibracion','$altavoz','$directorio','$tvAnalogico','$RadioFM','$conexionUSB','$tecladoQwerty','$EditorDocumentos','$juegos','$NeoNavegacion')";`

Comment: Buenas, has probado de construir dinámicamente la query poniendo sólo los campos que tienen valor?

Comment: No, como sería?

Comment: Si el campo es obligatorio y el string vacío no está permitido, entonces al validar los campos del formulario deberías detectarlo y generar el error correspondiente.

Comment: Construir la query dinamicamente significa que vas añadiendo los valores a la query, en tu caso en un insert necesitarias 2 variables para hacer esto, una con el `INSERT INTO (` y la otra con el `VALUES (` e ir añadiendo dentro del paréntesis las variables que no tengan valor NULL (controlado con IF ELSE o IIF), una vez acabes, cierras los paréntesis y juntas las 2 variables en una y te quedará la query entera.

Comment: Tienes razón en eso, pero había visto querys de inserción donde no era necesario las comillas simples para los strings. Pero no puedo encontrarlos para tomarlos como ejemplo.

Comment: ¿Estás metiendo directamente los valores en la query, en lugar de usar queries parametrizadas?

Comment: Ya lo solucioné como me lo propuso Marc, Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que hice fue una condición, donde si los campos obligatorios, son nulos, me salga un mensaje de notificación de falla de registro y me retorne nuevamente a la vista de registro, de lo contrario, que ejecute mi consulta de inserción.

Código:

```
if (
    $modelo==NULL || $marca==NULL || $tecnologia==NULL || $precioSinIva==NULL || $precioConIva==NULL || $FechaMarcaje==NULL || $DetalleHablador==NULL
){

    $message = "--- Falló el registro del equipo, intente nuevamente ---";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message'); 
    window.location.href = 'habladores_agregar.php'; </script>";
    pg_close($db_connection);
} else {
    $insert_value = "INSERT INTO equipos (id_secuencia, modelo, marca, tecnologia, sin_ivaa, con_ivaa, android, windows, bada, symbian, fecha_marcaje, detalle_hablador, tactil, tda, camara_foto, camara_video,
  mp3, mp4, internet, wifi, gps, bluetooth, social, microsd, pc, sms, mms, email, calculadora, alarma, vibracion, altavoz, directorio, tv, radio, usb, qwerty, editor, juegos, neo) 
  VALUES (1,'$modelo','$marca','$tecnologia',$precioSinIva,$precioConIva,'$android','$Bada','$Symbian','$Windows_Mobile','$FechaMarcaje','$DetalleHablador','$PantallaTactil','$TvDigital','$CamaraFotografica','$CamaraVideo','$mp3','$mp4','$internet',
   '$wifi','$gps','$bluetooth','$accesoRedesSociales','$RanuraMicroSd','$sincronizacionPC','$MensajeTexto','$MensajeMultimedia','$CorreoElectronico','$Calculadora','$Despertador','$Vibracion','$altavoz','$directorio','$tvAnalogico','$RadioFM','$conexionUSB','$tecladoQwerty',
    '$EditorDocumentos','$juegos','$NeoNavegacion')";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes una pregunta relacionada:

- [reporting services expression avoid comma if the field value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742367/reporting-services-expression-avoid-comma-if-the-field-value-is-null)

Debes usar un procedimiento almacenado:

```
SELECT COALESCE(address + ',', '') + COALESCE(city + ',', '') + ...
```